# Can one side edge be rounded in adobe xd?

Tags: layers, shapes, mask, adobe-xd

For a rectangle, it is possible to round a single side,
but when I am using a **triangle** all the sides are getting rounded at the same time.

Please see the image for your reference.

[image: Video]

What if I want to make the top edge rounded and the rest should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way in XD to round only one corner directly using the corner widget alone, but it is possible using boolean subtract and union operations and several shapes to achieve such an edit.

Like this

[image]

Here's how I did it:

1. Create a polygon, and duplicate it, apply curves to the one on top, then use a subtraction boolean operation using a rectangle to hide the lower portion of the curved polygon.
2. Select the bottom polygon (the uncurved one), and again use a rectangle to perform a subtract boolean to hide the upper part of the polygon.
3. Select all the pieces, and apply a union boolean to all of them.

Since booleans are non-destructive in XD, which is a really helful feature, you can still select the curved polygon and change the curve.

Comment: Dear @Billy Kerr Thanks :) and I appreciate the knowledge you have.

Comment: @SumitYadav - Glad you found it useful!